# deselecting buttons on rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

viewcontroller A goes to B and then comes back to A. I have a UIButton, in each of the cells of a UItableview in viewcontrollerA. When you click the button, the button highlights and goes to viewcontrollerB. I want the buttons to deselect when you go back to viewcontrollerA. 
The highlighting of the buttons work great is the deselecting that is the issue.

in cellforrowatindexpath, i have this:

```
        if(indexPath.row==selectedbuttonindex)
        {
            addpeople.selected=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            addpeople.selected=NO;
        }

            UIImage *buttonImageNormal =[UIImage imageNamed:@"addtochatNormal.png"];
                 UIImage *buttonImageSelected =[UIImage imageNamed:@"addtochatSelected.png"];
           [addpeople addTarget:self action:@selector(addpeopletoChat:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


                [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageSelected     forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


                 [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                  [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

                  addpeople.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 51, 44);

                  [cell.contentView addSubview:addpeople];
```

the selecting of the buttons and changing of view controllers is achieved with the following method:

```
  -(void) addpeopletoChat : (UIButton*)button{



       UITableViewCell *cell_ = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
       NSIndexPath *index_Path = [topictableView indexPathForCell:cell_];
       NSLog(@"%@", index_Path);
   selectedbuttonindex=index_Path.row;
  [topictableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index_Path]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   countaddpeople=countaddpeople+1;

  addpeopletochatViewController* viewcontrollerB = [[addpeopletochatViewController alloc]    init];
   viewcontrollerB.viewcontrollerA=self;

   [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];//changes view to viewcontroller B


  }
```

this was supposed to deselect it

```
  -(void) somefuction{

  NSLog(@"%d", selectedbuttonindex);
   NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0,selectedbuttonindex};
   NSIndexPath *index_Path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];
   selectedbuttonindex=-1;
   NSLog(@"%@" @"%@", @"hi", index_Path);

   [topictableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index_Path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

   }
```

in the h file of viewcontroller B i have:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import "officerTopicsViewController.h"

  @class officerTopicsViewController;
  @interface addpeopletochatViewController : UIViewController{


  }
  @property (nonatomic,retain) officerTopicsViewController *viewcontrollerA;

  @end
```

and in its m file i have:

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {

 [viewcontrollerA somefunction];


  }
```

But it stills doesn't work though

Note: i can't put selectedbuttonindex=-1; in view will appear because of how my view controllers work

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: trying again I see...does somefunction get called?   Did you try reloading the entire table instead of just trying to reload the old selected index?

Comment: thanks again, your solution worked, once again it was because of how i was changing view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Something that you could use, (though I don't know if this is the best way) would be to set the default image for your buttons whenever your view loads in the `viewDidLoad` method. So just:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Whatever you have in here...
     yourButtonName setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"addtochatNormal.png"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Or something along those lines.

If I didn't get your question right, let me know.